# ¿Se dice "tocar a rebato", "tocar a arrebato" o "tocar arrebato"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones

Con cierta frecuencia se lee la expresión *tocar a rebato*:

> Ya no vamos a **tocar a rebato** para informar de que hay fuego, pero sí podemos hacerlo contra la violencia machista.
>
> <sub>[Las campanas tocan a rebato en defensa propia](https://elpais.com/politica/2018/03/27/diario_de_espana/1522104337_588227.html), El País, 27 de marzo de 2018</sub>

[*Rebato*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VJfMrSm) es palabra recogida por el DLE, pero también [*arrebato*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3h8IU2z%7C3hAaJAi), por lo que la pronunciación suele ser indistinguible.

¿Cuál de estas formas es correcta?

- *tocar a rebato*
- *tocar a arrebato*
- *tocar arrebato*

Comment: La pronunciación no debe «soler» ser indistinguible, siempre será.  La preposición *a* por ser átona se pronuncia como si fuese elemento de la siguiente palabra.

Comment: También puede ser "toque **DE** rebato". De Cien años de soledad: "Cuando el pirata Francis Drake asaltó a Riohacha, en el siglo XVI, la bisabuela de Úrsula Iguarán se asustó tanto
con el **toque de rebato** y el estampido de los cañones, que perdió el control de los nervios y se sentó en un fogón
encendido."

Comment: @guifa no hay distinción entre las pronunciaciones de *"tocar a rebato"* y *"tocar arrebato"*, pero entre ellos y *"tocar* ***a*** *arrebato"* sí, no? (Noto que la pregunta en el título es sutilmente distinta que la del cuerpo).

Comment: @ukemi llevas razón, a medida que fui redactando perdí el foco del título original. He editado la pregunta y la respuesta para cubrir todos los flancos. Siéntete libre de editar algo si ves que tiene incorrecciones, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con este significado, y dado que *rebato* y *arrebato* son sinónimas, son válidas *tocar a rebato* y *tocar a arrebato*, si bien ***tocar a rebato*** es más común.
Lo que es incorrecto es decir *tocar arrebato*, una forma de escribirlo seguramente heredera de oír *tocar a rebato* y asociar la preposición *a* como elemento de la siguiente palabra, la cual es la conocida *arrebato*.

Esto nos lo explica el DPD, de cuya entrada he quitado los ejemplos:

> [**rebato**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=NpUb51BvFD6vZZdiA7). **Se usa normalmente en la locución *tocar a rebato***, que, además de su sentido recto, tiene el figurado de ‘dar la señal de alarma ante cualquier peligro’. Es también válida, aunque rara hoy, la variante *arrebato*.

Luego en el artículo correspondiente de *arrebato* dice:

> [**arrebato**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=arrebato). ‘Acción de arrebatarse’ y ‘furor causado por la vehemencia de alguna pasión’: «Allí la abraza y la besa en arrebato fogoso y peliculero» (ASantos Estanquera [Esp. 1981]). **Es poco frecuente su uso como sinónimo de *rebato*: *tocar a arrebato*** (→ [rebato](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=NpUb51BvFD6vZZdiA7)).

Es interesante también ver la evolución en el uso hasta convertir el uso de *arrebato* en este contexto en algo marginal, [según Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tocar%20a%20rebato%2Ctocar%20a%20arrebato%2Ctocar%20arrebato&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctocar%20a%20rebato%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctocar%20a%20arrebato%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctocar%20arrebato%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Todo ello viene del hecho que se esté usando *arrebato* en su segunda entrada, que ha caído en desuso en favor de *rebato*, tal y como indica el DLE:

> [**arrebato<sup>2</sup>**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3h8IU2z%7C3hAaJAi)
>   1. m. desus. [rebato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VJfMrSm).
>
> [**rebato**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VJfMrSm)
>   `Del ár. hisp. ribáṭ 'servicio en rábida', y este del ár. clás. ribāṭ.`
>
> 1. m. Convocación de los vecinos de uno o más pueblos, hecha por medio de campana, tambor, almenara u otra señal, con el fin de defenderse cuando sobreviene un peligro.
> 2. m. Alarma o conmoción ocasionada por algún acontecimiento repentino y temeroso.
> 3. m. Mil. Acometimiento repentino que se hace al enemigo.
>
> *de rebato*
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. De improviso, repentinamente.
>
> *tocar a rebato*
>   1. loc. verb. Dar la señal de alarma ante cualquier peligro.
>   2. loc. verb. desus. Se empleaba para expresar el peligro de una incursión repentina del enemigo sobre el pueblo, al cual se avisaba tocando aprisa las campanas para que se pusiese en defensa.